# How does the editing quality of officially published 5e material compare to that of 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e

5e is a much more mechanically simple game than 3.5e and if we concern ourselves only with first party, officially published, fully edited, non-playtest material such as the official books, we find that the release pace of 5e has been **much** slower than 3.5e. In total, one would hope that the editing quality of 5e has been superior to that of 3.5e. But has this actually turned out to be the case?

To give some examples of how this question can be answered without too much focus on opinion-based elements, here are some objective standards for how we can say that the editing of 3.5e was poor:

- Lack of due care. Examples include:

  - [This handbook](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?267985-Completely-Dysfunctional-Handbook-3-5) counts almost 1,000 dysfunctional rules in 3.5e. This includes blunders such as example characters being invalid, things imported from 3e that no longer make sense in 3.5e, or rules having a clear disparity between RAI and RAW.
  - Poor errata quality. Notorious cases include the [Rainbow Servant's "text trumps table" issue](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159902/53359), [WotC simply giving up after failing to fix Polymorph](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156515/53359), and the *Tome of Battle* errata becoming a copy and paste of the errata for *Complete Mage* halfway through.
  - Books that are notorious for their poor editing, such as *Serpent Kingdoms*.
- Game design blunders. Examples include:

  - [The huge disparity between the usefulness of classes](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?269440-Why-Each-Class-Is-In-Its-Tier-(Rescued-from-MinMax)).
  - Classes that were obviously never playtested. The Truenamer is particularly notorious for this. It is not broken as in overpowered, it's broken as in "does not work without the DM houseruling over the gaps and contradictions in its rules".
  - Feats that are either "trap choices" (what Druid doesn't take Natural Spell at level 6? And several PHB feats) or make your character worse despite appearing to be improvements (e.g. [Vow of Poverty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19128/53359)).
  - Several of the items in *Weapons of Legacy* make your character worse in exchange for giving you [things that you could have easily obtained elsewhere](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100857/53359).
  - [Epic Spellcasting is either useless or game-breaking depending on what version you allow, no middle ground](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22268/53359).

So, to repeat my question, how does 3.5e compare to 5e in non-opinion based editing regards such as these?

Comment: I think this is a great question... but an impossible one to back up, that’s going to invite a ton of speculation in lieu of people backing it up. Even if someone actually has the expertise and perspective to feel confident in their own answer, how could they possibly convey that perspective in a single answer?

Comment: @KRyan If 5e is equal or worse than 3.5e in these regards, then bullet points linking to evidence (similar to what's in the question) would be a strong step in the right direction. If 5e is much better, then all that would be needed would be something like "here is an almost exhaustive list of similar issues in 5e, notice how small it is". If however, 5e is only slightly better, I can see the difficulty.

Comment: That would be an extremely flawed analysis—it would be impossible to control for 3.5e’s age and tremendous quantity of analysis. How would we ever know that 5e merely doesn’t have those things _yet_? Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.